# Do USB3 to HDMI adapters have their own graphics card?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

Just looking for confirmation here but do devices like this have their own graphics card built-in? I know it says "External video card" in the description but on many listings for devices like that, it's a bit vague.

https://www.scan.co.uk/products/startech-usb-30-to-hdmi-external-video-card-multi-monitor-adapter-with-1-usb-pass-through-port-1920x

So if a (2nd) external monitor was plugged in via one of these devices, graphics performance would probably be a **lot** less than the on-board graphics card on a laptop?

We've used several devices like this to add 2nd screens to laptops but they are only used by office type users. We've got a graphic designer joining and the requirements have stepped up. Getting detailed information on display ports is often tricky. For example, this AMD based laptop appears to be able to drive up to four monitors using a USB-C to DisplayPort adapter:

https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad%20A485/ThinkPad_A485_Platform_Specifications.pdf

I assume this method would use the on-board graphics card to drive the monitors?

But this model can't support USB-C to DisplayPort and therefore can't natively support multiple monitors?

https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad%20E580/ThinkPad_E580_specs.pdf

My take on this is USB-C to DisplayPort is more of a splitter kind of technology whereas the USB3-HMDI is a separate graphics chip?

Comment: No, don't think so. Just signal converters, probably. Some hardware to tell the motherboard through drivers "Hey send me display information" and a conversion of that to HDMI.

Answer (score 3):

It varies. The USB-C connector can directly carry various different protocols as "Alternate modes" – the port can switch from traditional USB to HDMI, DisplayPort, Thunderbolt, analog audio (on phones), possibly Ethernet.

Simple USB-C adapters use the HDMI or DisplayPort alternate modes, so they attach to the existing GPU and directly receive the apropriate signal from it (or possibly converting HDMI↔DP). They **aren't** "splitters" though – they only expose outputs that the GPU already provides, like traditional DP/HDMI-out ports do.

Thunderbolt-based adapters contain their own GPU (as it is just PCI-Express behind the scenes). This does not necessarily mean lower performance; on the contrary, many such "external GPU" products exist to improve performance over the laptop's integrated low-power unit. External GPU devices are noticeably larger than plain HDMI/DP adapters.

(There also exist USB display adapters based on proprietary mechanisms like DisplayLink – these show up as a virtual GPU, but the hardware is just a simple frame buffer and all rendering is CPU-based.)

> But this model can't support USB-C to DisplayPort and therefore can't natively support multiple monitors?

The spec sheet shows a traditional HDMI output, and says that "two independent displays" are supported. I think this means the internal panel + one external HDMI display.

The [Lenovo website for E580](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-e-series/ThinkPad-E580/p/22TP2TEE580) claims that the model supports DisplayPort over its USB-C port, but some online reviews say that it didn't work.

> My take on this is USB-C to DisplayPort is more of a splitter kind of technology whereas the USB3-HMDI is a separate graphics chip?

In both cases it's most likely that the adapter just uses the corresponding "alternate mode" of the USB-C port. Whether it's HDMI or DP doesn't change things much.

Comment: Thanks for this - the information on alternate modes over USB-C wasn't something I was aware of.

Comment: I am using  a DisplayLink device. it works for general programming but  starts losting frames in YouTube, etc.

Comment: @MosheL: Yes, that might be either the part where your CPU has to do all rendering that a GPU would normally do, or the part where USB 2.0 isn't fast enough for the raw video stream (1080p at 60fps is nearly 3 Gbps or 400 MB/s!) and the CPU has to do compression on top of everything.

Comment: I have a USB3 DisplayLink device. it works with two screens but  its not the best.

Comment: This is incorrect when it comes to Thunderbolt. I've looked up multiple sources and Thunderbolt has always been compatible with DisplayPort, it even shared the mini-DP connector at the beginning. Thunderbolt 2 and 3 are even DP 1.2 compatible. My 20 euro cable doesn't even get slightly toasty while displaying a high res picture at 60 Hz. With a discrete GPU, that would certainly not be the case. Thunderbolt 3 mixes USB, PCIe **and** DP. And USB-4 will just be Thunderbolt, more or less if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> So if a (2nd) external monitor was plugged in via one of these devices, graphics performance would probably be a lot less than the on-board graphics card on a laptop?

Well, i own an adapter like this one, USB 3.0 to VGA, from another vendor... works fine for low end stuff like, in my case, programming, SSH...

BUT, for Youtube, for example, just lost frames in fast scenes. So, depends what you doing.

Comment: Your adapter is probably DisplayLink-based, because that's all a traditional USB 2.0/3.0 port can do. OP is asking about Type-C ports which have additional capabilities and can use "native" adapters.

Comment: Thanks for this - confirms what I suspected esp. with the additional bit of information on DisplayLink above

Answer (score 0):

It depends if USB to display devices carry a separate graphics card or GPU.

There are different devices out there.

---

Discrete graphics: are always compatible, even with USB-2. But don't expect too much from video (this may still be OK for higher end DisplayLink devices but certainly not with the crap chipset of the StarTech product - I'd expect glitches as well, they are reported on the internet anyway). You'll also have to deal with lower latency (slight delays) and please, just forget about 3D. Very fast scrolling may also be an issue. I'd always prefer the graphics of the host device, so if it has a HDMI output: use it!

---

Sometimes a simple USB-C to DisplayPort cable suffices if the USB-C carries alt-DP. In that case the GPU of the system will drive the screens at full performance. Thunderbolt 2/3 ports will always carry an alt-DP signal compatible with DP 1.2. So in that case you can just use one of these cables and even daisy chain if the monitor also has DP-out.

Your ThinkPad A485 example carries *two* ports that are alt-DP capable, so indeed that would be 4 monitors if you daisy chained two monitors each (!).

The E580 only has one of these ports, but that should still be enough for one relatively high res screen, the user manual states 3840 x 2160 pixels / 60 Hz (that's a single 4K screen), which **probably** means that it is DP 1.2 capable (as this seems to require HDR2) and that daisy chaining should be an option (a bit of research shows that this is possible, but not at 4K / 60Hz).

---

Note that there are also USB-C to high res HDMI cables available. These don't explicitly state it, but it seems that these rely on a DP to HDMI converter chip. Those are nice and cheap, but they don't include discrete graphics. So it might well be that you cannot use them even on USB-C that don't carry alt-DP.

Comment: Writing this on two QHD displays @ 60Hz, one connected to a *slightly too cheap* dock with two DP at the back - only using one - and a USB-C to DP cable. And my ThinkPad screen of course. Yay :)